# create a new array based on a function

Tags: php, html

I'm just learing to use php, and I've been working on this code that is not very efficient because it is very long and I would like it to be more automated. The idea is to generate a table with 2 colums, one with the user name and the other with the score of each user. As you may imagine, the score is based on a function that use other variables of the same user. My goal is to only have to set one variable for each user and a new row is would be created automatically at the end of the table.

```
<?php
$array1['AAA'] = "aaa"; ## I'm suposed to only set the values for array1, the rest
$array1['BBB'] = "bbb"; ## should be automatic
$array1['ETC'] = "etc";

function getscore($array1){
   ## some code
   return $score;
   };

$score['AAA'] = getscore($array1['AAA']);
$score['BBB'] = getscore($array1['BBB']);
$score['ETC'] = getscore($array1['ETC']);
?>
<-- Here comes the HTML table --->
<html>
<body>
<table> 
<thead> 
  <tr> 
      <th>User</th> 
      <th>Score</th> 
  </tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
  <tr> 
      <td>AAA</td> <-- user name should be set automaticlly too -->
      <td><?php echo $score['AAA'] ?></td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
      <td>BBB</td> 
      <td><?php echo $score['BBB'] ?></td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
      <td>ETC</td> 
      <td><?php echo $winrate['ETC'] ?></td> 
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: What exactly is your question?  What have you tried?

Comment: is there any way to simplify this code and to automatically generate the rows base on the value for $array1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$outputHtml = ''
foreach( $array1 as $key => $val ) 
{
    $outputHtml .= "<tr> ";
    $outputHtml .= "      <td>$key</td>";
    $outputHtml .= "      <td>".getscore($array1[$key]);."</td>";
    $outputHtml .= "  </tr>";
}
```

then in `$outputHtml` will be html content with all rows you wanna display

Answer (score 0):

This is a little cleaner, using `foreach` and `printf`:

```
<?php

$array1 = array(
  ['AAA'] => "aaa",
  ['BBB'] => "bbb",
  ['ETC'] => "etc"
);

function getscore($foo) {
   ## some code
   $score = rand(1,100); // for example
   return $score;
};

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
  $score[$key] = getscore($array1[$key]);
}

$fmt='<tr>
      <td>%s</td>
      <td>%s</td>
  </tr>';

?>
<-- Here comes the HTML table --->
<html>
<body>
<table><thead>
  <tr>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Score</th>
  </tr></thead><tbody><?php

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
  printf($fmt, $key, $score[$key]);
}

?>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I'll just note that you don't seem to be using the values of `$array1` anywhere.  Also, 
I'm not sure what `$winrate` is in your code, so I ignored it.